# SQL Query - referencing inner query

Tags: mysql

I'm not an seasoned SQL writer, but can do generic selects and joins, but I have a more complicated SQL that I'm trying to write where I need to grab a inner result set and the do some joins based on it.

My sub or inner query is as such:

```
 ( 
 SELECT    a.item_code, 
                     Concat('$', Format(Sum(a.standard),2, 'tan_in')) AS `standard`, 
                     concat('$', format(sum(a.si),2, 'tan_in'))       AS `si`, 
                     concat('$', format(sum(a.tessco),2, 'tan_in'))   AS `tessco price list` 
 FROM      ( 
                           SELECT DISTINCT t.item_code, 
                                           t.standard, 
                                           t.si, 
                                           t.tessco 
                           FROM            `tabitem price` AS t1 
                           JOIN 
                                           ( 
                                                           SELECT DISTINCT p.item_code,IF(p.price_list = "Standard Selling", p.price_list_rate, 0)  as standard,
                                                                           IF(p.price_list = "SI",p.price_list_rate,0)                  AS si,
                                                                           IF(p.price_list = "Tessco Price List", p.price_list_rate, 0) AS tessco
                                                           FROM            `tabitem price` p 
                                                           INNER JOIN      `tabitem price` r 
                                                           ON              r.item_code = p.item_code
                                                           ORDER BY        item_code) t 
                           ON              t1.item_code = t.item_code) a 
 LEFT JOIN `tabitem` tabi 
 ON        tabi.NAME = a.item_code 
 GROUP BY  a.item_code) AS final
```

And outside of this I have:

```
SELECT
tabCustomer.customer_name AS 'Customer::150', 
CONCAT(FORMAT(`tabPricing Rule`.discount_percentage,2),'%%') AS 'Discount %%', 
`tabPricing Rule`.item_group AS 'Discount Group',
`tabPricing Rule`.title AS 'Discount Title',
final.item_code AS 'Item::125', 
tabItem.description AS 'Description::250',
`tabItem Price`.price_list AS 'Price List::125',
final.Standard AS 'List Price',
final.SI AS 'SI Price',
CONCAT('$', FORMAT(`tabItem Price`.price_list_rate,2)) AS 'Customer Price::125',
IF(`tabPricing Rule`.item_group = "Top level", CONCAT('$', FORMAT(`tabItem Price`.price_list_rate * (1-(`tabPricing Rule`.discount_percentage/100)),2)), if(`tabPricing Rule`.item_group = tabItem.item_group, CONCAT('$', FORMAT(`tabItem Price`.price_list_rate * (1-(`tabPricing Rule`.discount_percentage/100)),2)), CONCAT('$', FORMAT(`tabItem Price`.price_list_rate,2)))) AS 'Discounted Price',
tabItem.item_group AS 'Category::100',
tabItem._user_tags AS 'User Tag::100'
FROM final
```

/* inner query goes here */

```
WHERE tabitem.disabled = '0' 
AND  tabitem.item_group != 'Third Party Components' 
AND  tabitem.item_group != 'Engineering Services' 
AND  tabitem.item_group != 'Services' 
ORDER BY tabitem.item_group, 
         tabitem._user_tags, 
        `tabitem price`.price_list_rate;
```

When I run this it says that 'final' table does not exist.

My question is how do i reference the inner result set?

Thank you.

Regards,

JR

Comment: For that matter where is tabcustomer, `tab pricing rule`  and it looks like you have from final (inner query as final)   so do you have a table called final or should from final be from (Inner query) and all the selects reference "FINAL"?

Comment: ***My question is how do i reference the inner result set?*** you don't.  You carry up the columns you need and reference them from FINAL. (your derived table)  Or you create your inner query as a CTE (or a view) and select from it but only available in recent version of mySQL.

Comment: @xQbert - Thanks, I think my best option is to use a CTE (view).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the problem or was an error on the transcript.

But right now you have

```
FROM final  
/* inner query goes here */

WHERE tabitem.disabled = '0'
```

When you should have

```
FROM ( * inner query goes here */ ) as final  

WHERE tabitem.disabled = '0'
```

Also I dont see where you include `tabitem` in the outside query.